# Swift change color of NavigationControl and TabBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I wanna change the color of the back button of the NavigationControl of all the app, how can I do it? I want to have it in red instead of the normal blue button...

And I have a problem with my TabBar.
I have changed the icons color and name from standard blue to red with these:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState:.Selected)
```

And this

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

var color = UIColor.redColor()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

But I have more than 5 tabs, so I have the button "More", and when I press it, the icons aren't red but blue, and when I press to edit the tab bar icons, the name of the tab is in red, but the icon not.
What can I do?
Picture to explain:
http://postimg.org/image/67oqa15ll/

Answer (score 7):

To change text and Icon's color for all UITabBarItems throughout the application (in Swift / Xcode 6) :

In the AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: your_color ], forState: .Selected)

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = your_color

    return true

}
```

And that will do the trick !

Comment: It works in the tabBar, but in the "more" section, the other icons are still in blue...

Comment: In Swift 3.0 instead of **forState:** use **for:**. UIControlState.Selected is also slightly changed to lowercase:`UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: your_color], for: .selected)`

Answer (score 1):

try this in your firstViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            var view: UITableView = self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view as UITableView
            view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            if view.subviews.count != 0 {
                for cell in view.visibleCells() {
                    cell.textLabel??.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                }
            }
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and this in your UITabbarController

```
class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController,UITabBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didBeginCustomizingItems items: [AnyObject]) {
        self.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
}
```

Example Project https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbm4l60cnvyrf5h/UItabbarCustomizing.zip?dl=0

I hope I helped you

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. You solved my problem with the NavigationController, but I have problems with the TabBar too. In "More", how can I change icons' color from blue to red? And how can I let it works too in "Edit" page inside more?

Comment: Thanks you, it works on the tabBar, but there is a bug with "More" tab. When I press it, it opens a table with my others tab, with theirs icon, but the problem is that there the icons aren't red, but these are still blue... How to fix it?

Comment: Thats my problem: http://postimg.org/image/bcw1q66cp/     The color doesn't works in more, but only in the tabBar, instead the text works. I want all the icons in red instead of blue.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it still doesn't work, and I don't know how to upload my project here... I have this in AppDelegate, but if I put it also in any viewController, nothing changes...   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState:.Selected)
        UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1LnFOxKF9A_ZWZqaWM1ZnEzQzg&usp=drive_web

Comment: I'm so sorry, try now!

Comment: Can you see it now? Have you got any idea to fix that?

Comment: Thank you, let me know when you have any idea or you fixed it!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Nothing? I still have this problem :(

Comment: if you need I can send a test project for swift and objective c

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll watch it for sure!

Comment: Where did you added it? I can't find it

Comment: Example Project https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbm4l60cnvyrf5h/UItabbarCustomizing.zip?dl=0enter link description here